# Rails migration index name for partitioned database table is too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, activerecord, migration, sharding

My Rails application's database is partitioned into shards, with `partition_key` of each shard being `toyota_seller_account_id`.
Now I want to create a table called `agg_product_summary_breakdowns` using this migration:

```
class CreateAggProductSummaryBreakdowns < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :agg_product_summary_breakdowns, partition_key: :toyota_seller_account_id do |t|
      t.references :toyota_seller_account, null: false
      t.date :summary_date, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :agg_product_summary_breakdowns
  end
end
```

Now Rails will automatically create an index on `toyota_seller_account_id` with name `index_agg_product_summary_breakdowns_on_toyota_seller_account_id` because it is the partition key.

However, I will then encounter this error:

`ArgumentError: Index name 'index_agg_product_summary_breakdowns_on_toyota_seller_account_id' on table 'agg_product_summary_breakdowns' is too long; the limit is 63 characters`. Unfortunately it is just 64 characters long (1 longer than what's permitted).

I want to keep the table name as it is, i.e. `agg_product_summary_breakdowns` and the partition key cannot be changed either. Is there a way to override the index name that I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the name of the index. Try with:

```
t.references :toyota_seller_account, null: false, index: {name: :whatever_you_want}
```

Comment: Hi can you please help me to resolve my issue? Here's my issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822347/rails-no-connection-pool-for-publicactivityormactiverecordactivity Thanks in advance!