# Rails: No connection pool for PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rake, public-activity

I'm trying to upgrade an existing project from Ruby 2.3 to Ruby 2.6

Everything was working fine until I received the following error on running `rake db:create`

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity
/home/user/project/engines/admin/lib/admin/activity_extension.rb:10:in `<module:Admin>'
/home/user/project/engines/admin/lib/admin/activity_extension.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/project/engines/admin/lib/admin/engine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/project/engines/admin/lib/admin.rb:1:in `require'
/home/user/project/engines/admin/lib/admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/project/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/project/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

I'm using postgresql as database and this is the `database.yml` file -

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: -------
  password: -------
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: mydbName
```

Is anyone having any idea why I'm getting this error?

Any kind of help would be greately appreciated!

Comment: Have you run `bundle update` after upgrade ruby ?

Comment: Yes I run the command ```bundle update``` after ruby upgrade and it went well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176304/rails-no-connection-pool-for-activerecordbase)

Comment: @AlterLagos No. I've tried all the solutions that are mentioned there and nothing works for me.